# Issue while installing horizon "Exception calling Set Access Rule with 1 argument"

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, powershell, horizon

I am installing Horozon. While installing at step "SetPermission : FilePermission" I am getting following exception

[------------------------------------------ SetPermissions : FilePermissions -----------------------------------------]
[SetPermissions]:[Allow] IIS AppPool\horizon.sc930sc.dev.local
[SetPermissions]:[Path] C:\inetpub\wwwroot\horizon.sc930sc.dev.local
[SetPermissions]:[Rights] FullControl
System.Object[]
[SetPermissions]:[Propagate] None
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Exception calling "SetAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identity
references could not be translated."
At C:\D Drive\Softwares\Sitecore Horizon 9.3.0\Public\Install-AuthoringHost.ps1:85 char:5
+     Install-SitecoreConfiguration @sitecoreAH -WorkingDirectory $wrkm ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:00:10
Invoke-FilePermissionsTask : Exception calling "SetAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identity references
could not be translated."
At C:\Program
Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.2.0\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:641 char:25
+                         & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-FilePermissionsTask], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IdentityNotMappedException,Invoke-FilePermissionsTask

[image]

I checked for all the possible folder permissions but still unable to resolve this. Any help

**I am running PS in admin mode**

Comment: how did you solved it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the fix
Service "Application Host Helper Service" was not running

Comment: I was getting the same error while installing Sitecore 9.2 and above solution worked.